# I'm looking for a way to store search preferences for a user

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, parameters

I've got a C#/ASP.net application.  When a user searches for data using a few standard dropdowns and text boxes, I run a SQL query to grab all of the users search preferences and then auto-fill the controls based on what's returned.  The user can then search using those presets, or change any of the choices and search again.

The problem is, this requires a call to the DB every time that search page is loaded.  I was hoping there might be a way to grab all the preferences once when the user logs in the first time and then store them somehow, to lighten the load on my SQL Server db.  Has anyone ever come across this issue and discovered an efficient way to handle it?

Comment: you can load it after the user login into a data table and keep it in Session (if it's not very large)

Comment: @Claies, didn't OP clearly said in post `I've got a C#/ASP.net application`

Comment: @Claies, that's too granular, when post says `C#/ASP.NET` first thing I would take in mind it's a `Webform`. Moreover, you could relate WPF with ASP.NET is only when you would probably deploy/host your WPF app in a browser but in that case it's not ASP.NET at all.

Comment: @Claies I'd like to see a desktop (MVC or a WinForms) app created with ASP.NET. Never seen that before, not saying that it's impossible, though.

Answer (score 2):

What about using the old goodies - Cookies?

```
HttpCookie aCookie = new HttpCookie("SearchPreferences");
aCookie.Values = /* your collection of preferences */;
aCookie.Expires = /* DateTime of expiration */;
Response.Cookies.Add(aCookie);
```

... or sessions you would destroy when an user logs out?

```
if (Session["SearchPreferences"] != null) {
    /* loading the preferences */
} else {
    /* preferences are already loaded */
}
```

You can also set their expiration using `Session.TimeOut`.

**Edit:**

As it may sound from the discussion below, both of these methods have their pros and cons. For that I've thought that adding a few more should give your opportunity to choose what suits you best.

`System.Web.Caching.Cache` seems like the most modern and fastest way of doing this.

```
Cache c = System.Web.Caching.Cache();
c.Add(key, value, dependencies, absoluteExpiration, 
      slidingExpiration, priority, onRemoveCallback);
```

However, there's still an option of [`ApplicationState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178594%28v=vs.140%29.aspx), which is an object that can hold your values while the application is running.

Comment: @Claies The tag ASP.NET on the question makes it clear enough for me.

Comment: cookies are a bit problematic as not all browsers supports them, and those that does include an option to disable them. Also, if memory serves, they are very limited in storage space. Other then that, I don't see why not to use cookies for a web application.

Comment: +1 but I would prefer the `Session` suggestion over `Cookies` due to reason that 1. cookies could be disabled in customer machine 2. Cookies has size constraints.

Comment: @Rahul well, unless you go for `cookieless`, don't `Sessions`, in the context of persistence, go the same way?

Comment: @EdSF, How?? `Session` can't just be disabled by end user right? only can be by developers. Also, `Session` is not bound by a size constraint alike `Cookies`.

Comment: @Rahul How are "sessions" stored on client/browsers?

Comment: @Rahul Huh? Explain how a browser tells the server that "this is me and this is my session"....and not some other browser?

Comment: I was hesitant about cookies because there are approximately 16 search options.  Wasn't sure if I could get that many in a cookie, most of the demos I've seen indicated just a handful of values.

Comment: @EdSF, you mean if cookies disabled then session can't be used since session client keys are stored in cookies. In that make session cokkieless and the session keys will be send to server as query string. How is that completely bounded by Cookies. I don't see though. Moreover, I can use other session modes to have it more flexible.

Comment: @Rahul read my comment one more time - I explicitly mentioned `cookieless` :)

Comment: @EdSF, Ahh!! missed that point but even if cookies are enabled, size restriction can never be ignored. Moreover, now a days if your web app storing some data in client cookie; you will have to let client know that you are doing do. Some cyber law (show somewhere in internet). In a single sentence `Cookies` were the way in old times and not now. Nice conversation BTW.

Comment: @Rahul and thank you both for your little spam on my inbox :) So, what's the conclusion?

Comment: @user35443 Ha ha! Sorry. See my answer. In the end you can choose what suits your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for client-side persistence, `Cookies` and `Sessions` (which still depend on cookies on the client, unless `cookieless`) is one option (see previous answer). You can also look into newer [client side persistence](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage) options (where `Web Storage` has most browser support). Hth...

Comment: First time I heard about `Web Storage`. New thing for me.

Comment: @Rahul it's pretty cool - more data and since it's key/value, learning curve isn't much - though just like everything else, with such power comes responsibility :)